# Set JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS for Jenkins inside Tomcat in Windows

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I am doing this : http://heylinux.com/en/?p=161

But, I couldn't find out how to add the parameter in `JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

I am deploying Jenkins from Tomcat in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I created `setenv.bat` in `tomcat\bin` and added this line:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
```

It worked.